# Fields duplicated during de-serialization

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a class which looks like this :

```
public class Item {
private ItemHeader header;
private ItemBody body; 
}

public class ItemHeader {
private int id;
private String name;  
}
public class ItemBody {
private List<String> values;
private List<String> details;
```

}

The fields of ItemHeader and ItemBody are accessible via setters and getters from the Item class as well as from their corresponding classes. All said setters and getters EXCEPT get/setItemBody +get/setItemHeader are annotated with @JsonIgnore.

When Item instance is returned by a GET REST method, the Response looks as following :

```
    {
  "body": {
    "details":[]
    "values":[]
  },
  "header": {
    "id": 145,
    "name": "name_of_item",
   },
    "details":[],
    "values":[],
    "id": 145,
    "name": "name_of_item"    
}
```

Internals of itemHeader and itemBody are spilled twice into the deserialized Json , once (correctly) inside the corresponding fields and the second time just outside them.

I do not have much control over Jackson definitions behind the scenes and can basically only control my class hierarchy with annotations and such.

Please advise - how to remove the duplication, the "spilled over" values...

Comment: I don't understand what your question is?

Comment: How to remove the duplication. Will add clarification,thanks

Comment: JsonIgnore annotation is enough for this. Maybe you have several json libraries in classpath, like codehaus and fasterxml, and these behaviour is caused by their conflict?

Comment: @AdamSkywalker might be. I'm importing only the fasterxml one though, so how would the other library have impact in this case?

Comment: I've added the @JsonIgnore when same issue happened on the serialization path and there it indeed solved the problem. So this is even more puzzling for me

Comment: it can be serialized with one library and deserialized with another, for example. there's no riddle here, just ensure you use the same tool for serialization and deserialization so the annotation could work.

Comment: Thanks! Will have to see what can I do to ensure that as serialization is done while inserting to a no-sql DB and not explicitly....

Comment: Consider showing the entire class source code, not just some value-free snippets.  Here is a revision of your question:  I'm trying to spell this hard word and I can't figure out if it has a x in it.  Does it have an X?

Comment: Thanks, but a. Problem solved and b. Can't be done.

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up removing the double layer of getters/setters which solved the issue, and in the process discovered that indeed, the serialization path and the de- path used different libraries . So https://stackoverflow.com/users/2513573/adamskywalker had the right idea